# How does SO mark posts as interesting at the home page?

Tags: support, questions, interesting-page

I am wondering how https://stackoverflow, the posts at the home page tab (interesting) mark posts as interesting.

When viewing most of these posts, they just look like new posts.

But when going to the *Questions* page, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions tab (newest), the overview is completely different.

How does SO generate the *interesting posts* at the home page? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes, your question is on-topic here.

Comment: Ok thanks, the blog post linked in duplicate awnsered my question.